# Kotlin extension function to an unknown type

Tags: kotlin, extension-function

Is it possible to use an extension function with a function that returns an unspecified value type?

```
defaultPreferences(this)["some string"]?.let { ...
```

I have to do this to avoid error, but I really want it to be in a single line.

```
val value: String? =  defaultPreferences(this)["some string"]
value?.let { ...
```

And the error I get in the first example is

```
"Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in inline operator fun <reified T : Any> SharedPreferences.get(key: String, defaultValue: T? = ...): T?
Please specify it explicitly."
```

Any ideas?

Edit: More information

Here is the declaration of the get function.

```
inline operator fun <reified T : Any> SharedPreferences.get(key: String, defaultValue: T? = null): T? {
```

Comment: Where are the generics here?  Can you show the definitions of everything involved?

Comment: The get function that I am calling with [ ] returns : T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
defaultPreferences(this).get<String?>("some string")?.let {
```

?

Comment: This kind of works, too bad I can't keep the brackets D:
Thanks!

Comment: My other idea was casting directly to `String?` but I've just checked and it wouldn't have worked despite the tricks I tried with it. So this is actually the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

If your inline function is what I think it is (`when` on `T::class` and different typed gets like `getString`, `getInt` etc. with unsafe cast of the result) You should refrain from using it.

While slightly shorter to type it generates a lot of garbage bytecode, and puts unnecessary strain during runtime (`when` cases are evaluated when program runs - but You already know their outcome before compiling).

For some bytecode samples You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52527282/9241978) to related question.

Comment: Yeah, and also would cause unexpected runtime crashes if, for example, you had `private val myValue: Int?` and later `myValue = sharedPreferences["key"]` and then someone changed `myValue` to `String?`. Nothing would fail to compile but at runtime you're going to be trying to cast an Int to a String. Better to be type-safe!